# How to get updated Context's state values to it's child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a react application ,So I need to get an immediate update to all the children of Context component in a change of the state of Context component but I can't get the updated context values .

```
export default class Home extends Component{
    state = {
       user:{name:"Rob"},

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({user:this.context.user});
    }

    render(){
         return(
              <DetailsConsumer>
                   {value=>(
                        <button onClick={value.setName} >
                    )}
              </DetailsConsumer>



);
}
```

```
class DetailsProvider extends Component{

    state={
       user:{}
    }


     setName= ()=>{
        this.setState({user:{name:"Hasindu"}})
     }
    render(){
        return(<DetailsContext.Provider value={
            {user:this.state.user,

                changeName:this.changeName

            }
        }>

            {this.props.children}
        </DetailsContext.Provider>);
    }
}

const DetailsConsumer = DetailsContext.Consumer;
export{DetailsConsumer,DetailsProvider,DetailsContext};
```

SO What I need is when ever I click on the button of class Home and invoke the setName() method of DetailsProvider (Context) I need to update the context state to the object in setName() method and I also need to get the updated value to my Home class.[Which means I need to update my Home component state attribute user with that new value ]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Home` component is duplicating the context state, and therefore isn't getting its state updated when the context state updates. The best way to solve this is by removing the duplicate state in `Home` and using the context state directly.

```
export default function Home(){    
     return(
          <DetailsConsumer>
               {value=>(
                    <>{value.user.name}: <button onClick={value.setName} /></>
                )}
          </DetailsConsumer>
     )
}
```

Comment: can you explain it more further I mean why your saying It's duplicating?

Comment: You Probably Don't Need Derived State
 https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html